# Incoming data processing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I get json encoded information about more than 50K products. The task is to transfer all these products to the database. In this case, if there is a product with the current ID - the data about it should be simply put, otherwise - create the product.
For this I use the `foreach` loop and the `updateOrCreate` Laravel function.
Something like this:

```
$products = json_decode($jsonDecodedProducts, true);
foreach ($products as $product)
{
    Products::updateOrCreate(
    [ 'products_id' => $product['products_id'] ], 
        [
            'product_name' => $product['products_name'], 
        ]
    );
}
```

But it works quite slowly. Does Laravel provide any method for accelerating such a task?

Comment: maybe you should think of queuing data to processing

Comment: Fetch all product ids before starting the loop and manually check against that collection. Keep the records to be inserted in an array that you can all insert at once after you looped through the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORM not still is  the fastest solution, try write it with custom sql query.

here is discusion about similar https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/performant-way-to-mass-update-or-create

Comment: Thanks for the link. And I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel’s Eloquent ORM is quite slow by construction, due to - for example - the magic methods and attribute functionalities. My suggestion is to bypass these processes, by building raw queries using the `DB` facade.
In addition, you could save all the rows which need to be inserted in an array, and bulk insert them.

Comment: In which case I do not need this test. I can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: @Stranger That is true, indeed.